# How to extract the filename from a path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string

I have a string value which is `/Images/She.jpg`. I want only the part after the `/images/` i.e `She.jpg`. How to extract that part into a string?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("/Images/She.jpg");
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to delete that file.

Comment: Sure, you can use [System.IO.File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx) method to remove it.

Comment: Though, make sure that the `path` is correct.

Comment: So it Does.'t delete the fodler ? it only deletes the file in that folder ? sorry just a small confusion..

Comment: Yes, it'll only delete file, if you want to delete folder then you need to use `System.IO.Directory.Delete`

Answer (score 5):

If you're working with paths you should use the other answers. If it's only a plain string you're working with you can use following code:

```
string filePath = "/Images/She.jpg";
string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

Comment: Even when working with plain strings, you should use the `Path` class. What happens here if the file you were given is relative to the current directory, such as `"She.jpg"`?

Answer (score 0):

This will work, as long as you don't have anything too complicated in your path, e.g. query parameters after the file name.

```
Path.GetFileName("/Images/She.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the GetFileName answers previously posted.

Alternatively, you can parse the string manually using IndexOf and Substring. I've included multiple variables so it's easy to see the steps of parsing a string.

```
var source = "/images/she.jpg";
var key = "/images/";
var target = source.IndexOf(key);
var start = target + key.Length;
var length = source.Length - start;
var result = source.Substring(start, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you could also split the string into an array and get the last element in the array...

```
string path = "/Images/She.jpg";
string[] arr = path.Split('/');
string filename = arr[arr.Length - 1];
```

or if you prefer a one liner

```
string path = "/Images/She.jpg";
string filename = path.Split('/').Last();
```

this will return

```
She.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can move backwards from the end of the string.

```
    private string GetFileName(string path)
    {
        string filename = null;

        for (int i = (path.Length - 1); i > -1; --i)
        {
            if (path[i].ToString() == "/")
            {
                for (int x = (i + 1); x < (path.Length); ++x)
                {
                    filename += path[x];
                }

                break;
            }
        }

        return (filename);
    }
```

This works backwards from the last char of the string until it hits a '/'. Then, it adds up all the characters after the '/' and returns that to you.

Comment: What a complicated approach.